# Need help,writing a python about defined function with Terminal Run

Tags: python, terminal

I am new to python and and currently learning to use def functions properly.

my def code in Sublime Text is following:

```
def quadratic(a,b,c):
    if not isinstance(a,(int,float)):
        raise TypeError('bad operand type')
    if not isinstance(b,(int,float)):
        raise TypeError('bad operand type')
    if not isinstance(c,(int,float)):
        raise TypeError('bad operand type')
    d = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
        if d < 0:
            print('no result!')
        if d = 0:
            x1 = -b / (2 * a)
            x2 = x1
            return x1,x2
        else:
            x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
            x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
            return x1,x2
```

but when I use Terminal(in Mac) to run this code,come into this error:

```
Frank-s-Macbook-Pro:Coding frank$ quadratic(1,2,1)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `1,2,1'
```

I would appreciate any assistance with my errors I must have made.

Comment: Rule 1:  read the error message.  It says `-bash: syntax error...`.  You are trying to run Python code in a different language, i.e. Bash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't run a python defined function straight from the terminal. In this case you probably would want to run the interpreter in the same folder as your script is by typing python in the terminal.

Then python starts up (if it is installed and aliased right). You can then import the function by importing the filename. Let's say your function is saved under the file myfunction.py. Then:

```
import myfunction (without the .py)
```

Then type:

```
>> myfunction.quadratic(a, b, c)
```

and you should get your answer returned to you.

If you want to run your script straight from the terminal you should look at the input function or sys.argv function and after rewriting execute your script with

```
$ python myfunction.py
```

edit:
there is also some errors in your code, see other answers :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the mac bash, but shoudln't the call be:

```
 python quadratic(1,2,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you got at least 2 syntax errors in your code...
corrected code:

```
def quadratic(a,b,c):
    if not isinstance(a,(int,float)):
        raise TypeError('bad operand type')
    if not isinstance(b,(int,float)):
        raise TypeError('bad operand type')
    if not isinstance(c,(int,float)):
        raise TypeError('bad operand type')
    d = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
    if d < 0:
        print('no result!')
    if d == 0:
        x1 = -b / (2 * a)
        x2 = x1
        return x1,x2
    else:
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
        return x1,x2
```

after

> d = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c

if statement has wrong indent, and contains an error:

> if d = 0:

after these errors are corrected, you can run your code directly from Sublime (cmd+b)